# How to override search action in Jmesa?

Tags: jmesa

I am new to Jmesa. I want to know how to change or override search action which is provided by Jmesa?

I am using Jmesa-3.0.

Thanks ,

Answer (score 0):

Are you talking about altering how columns are filtered?  If so, [this page](http://code.google.com/p/jmesa/wiki/FilterMatcher) offers instructions that will hopefully serve as a good starting point.